# Getting highest available number in a List<string>

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I have the following strings in a `List<string>`

vs0, vs1, vs2, vs3, vs4, vs5, ... vs(n)

In my list, they are not sorted and are random. I want to get the string which has the highest `int` in it. And then get the number out of that string into a int var.

What is the best and fastest way do this?

Comment: What is the largest set of n that you need to be concerned with?

Comment: It will be less than 65535 :P but it is always random, maybe one time I get only 1 member in the list or 65535 string!

Comment: Then Yuriy's answer should more than suffice for your case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var max = myList.OrderByDescending(v => int.Parse(v.Substring(2))).First();
```

or if you need the highest int

```
var max = myList.Select(v => int.Parse(v.Substring(2))).Max();
```

Comment: Very clean LINQ but it usually is never the fastest (in terms of performance) way to do things.

Comment: isnt the ordering unnecessary and increasing the complexity.. he just needs to loop through the list once?

Comment: @Baz1nga it won't be a complete ordering, just enough to get the highest value. I personally would have gone with the MaxBy from MoreLinq, but this was just shorter.

Comment: OrderBy always does a complete ordering and is O(nlogn); Max is O(n). The shortest is `myList.Max(v => int.Parse(v.Substring(2)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
 var result = List.Max(p => int.Parse(p.Substring(2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about with LINQ:

```
List<string> strings = ...
int max = strings.Max(item => int.Parse(item.Substring(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just `l.Select(Convert.ToInt32).Max()`?

---

Per Jim's suggestion, need to strip the 2 leading characters:

```
l.Max(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(2)))
```

(but this one is practically the same as other answers).

Comment: That doesn't strip off the 'vs'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = yourList.Select(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(2)).Max();
```

Comment: There's no need to Select before doing Max, since Max accepts a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

`l.Select(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(2))).Max()`

You may want to create a separate list of `int`s if you plan on doing this more than once

Comment: SubString is a typo, and there's no need to Select before doing Max, since Max accepts a transformer.